# Programatically trigger a click on an AJAX enabled form field (button, select, etc)

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

Using `jQuery`, I need to programmatically click / select Form items (radios, select lists, checkboxes, etc). This field item has an `'#ajax'` action / callback defined using [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax).

The following code from a similar question works for submit buttons ([Programatically trigger a click on an AJAX enabled form submit button](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/11714/9378)):

`jQuery('#edit-submit').mousedown()`

However, this does not work for radio buttons. I have also tried creating a copy of the element and making my own AJAX call using the following code from another similar question ([Use Drupal7 AJAX goodness programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4840036/1527899)):

```
          base = 'edit-my-radio-button';
          element = '<input type="radio" id="'+base+'" name="cat-selector" value="garfield" class="form-radio ajax-processed">';
          element_settings = Drupal.ajax[base].element_settings;
          myAjax = new Drupal.ajax(base, element, element_settings);
          myAjax.eventResponse(element, 'click');
```

The AJAX call is made, but the screen does not update as if the user clicked it. How can I programmatically select a radio button or select list using `jQuery` and cause Drupal to execute the AJAX call?

Please note: I have purposely kept this question as open ended as possible. My hope is that there is a more general way to do this for all form element types and that future answers regarding these can be considered relevant so that we have a single resource for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to select radio buttons using `jQuery` I came up with the following solution:

```
base = 'edit-my-radio-button';
id = '#'+base;
$(id).click();
Drupal.ajax[base].eventResponse($(id), 'click');
```

After some digging around in `misc/ajax.js`, I found that Drupal AJAX stores the result of `new Drupal.ajax(base, element, element_settings)` in the `Drupal.ajax[]` JavaScript Array. This led me to realize that I did not need to create a fake `element` or an `element_settings` object as the [Use Drupal7 AJAX goodness programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4840036/1527899) answer suggested. While that simplified my code, and `eventResponse()` created a successful AJAX request, the AJAX commands being returned still did not execute.

On a hunch, I decided to use `.click()` followed by `.eventResponse()` because I noticed that `false` was being printed on the console.

After looking at the `.eventResponse()` code, I am not 100% sure where it is looking for the element to be currently selected. After stepping through the function calls, I believe `jquery.form.js` is checking to see if the item is selected, but since this file is minified by default, I have not gone through it yet. If anyone else can shed light on this or be willing to step through the function calls, that would be great!

FYI: If I run these commands manually in the console, `.eventResponse()` still returns `false`, so don't be alarmed when you see that.

Answer (score 0):

@MD3 Did you try to explicitly check the radio button before clicking it?

`$(id).attr('checked', true);`

I've had the same problem as you and doing that solved it.