# Call Remove Button (File Upload) Programmatically using JavaScript

Tags: webforms, entities

How can I call the remove button of temporary uploaded file programmatically using JavaScript?

[image]

I want to clear the form fields when the condition changes. I've done all the form fields exept the temporary uploaded file.

Can I call the remove function? If yes, Where is it?

Comment: Why don't you just `.trigger( "click" )` on that button? This is an universal jQuery method, but I see no reason for it to fail for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do is what @Molo mentioned in his comment.

```
$('#element_id').trigger("click"); OR $('.element_class').trigger("click");
$('#element_id').trigger("mousedown"); OR $('.element_class').trigger("mousedown");
```

Or you could, reset the .html() of the upload element

```
$('#'+id).html($('#'+id).html()); OR  $('.'+class).html($('.'+class).html());
```

JavaScript into Drupal can be done in various ways, you could reference your javaScript file in your theme's info file or you override the drupal_add_js function in template.php and add your JavaScript.

For more Information on how to put JavaScript into Drupal see [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/121997) or [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-to-add-javascript-to-my-drupal-site) and these ([module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) or [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation)) could also be handy. This [article](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/programatically-trigger-a-click-on-an-ajax-enabled-form-submit-button) explains how to programmatically submit a form in Drupal.

Here is a good tutorial, how to add your JavaScript to Drupal https://www.drupal.org/node/756722

Comment: You can even shorten that to `$('#element_id').click();`

Comment: @Clive could do, I went for trigger because its the new comer in JQuery, very very slightly faster performance wise. What I like the most about trigger is supplying the event-type as argument.

Comment: @Raf, the .trigger("click") event not working but .trigger("mousedown") works correctly.

Comment: @JohnCroneh, glad your problem is resolved, last step, kindly mark your question as resolved.

Comment: @Raf, Sorry for the delay.