# How to trigger the click on the field collection button "add another item" using jQuery

Tags: javascript, entities

I want to trigger click on "Add Another item" button of field collection on some jQuery event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('.field-add-more-submit').mousedown();
```

works in Inspector.

```
$('.field-add-more-submit').mousedown();
```

probably works from a module.

`.click()` doesn't work for some reason. More info [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/how-to-programmatically-trigger-a-click-on-an-ajax-enabled-form-submit-button).